# Getting error while running angular version

Tags: angular

When I write `ng -v` in the command, I get this:
`ng -v
-bash: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng: No such file or directory`
Can you tell me what does it mean and how can I solve this issue?

Comment: did you install `npm install -g @angular/cli`?

Comment: @Hareesh Yes, I've installed it.

Comment: did you install it globally with `-g` tag?

Comment: @Hareesh Yes, I think it's not so simple problem. I removed node_modules file before on /usr/local/lib in order to completely uninstall and then reinstall ng, but I've done something wrong.

Comment: Check your `package.json` . does angular cli listed there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Install node

```
1) check node version => `node --version`
2) check npm version  =>  `npm --version`
```

## Install angular/cli

```
1) npm i  @angular/cli@latest
2) npm i -g angular/cli@latest
```

## If already installed, you may uninstall and install again.

```
1) npm uninstall  @angular/cli@latest
2) npm uninstall  -g angular/cli@latest
```

## close terminal/close vs code and open again.

Check angular/cli version:-

```
1) check angular/cli version  =>  `ng --version`
```

Answer (score 0):

first you have to remove completly

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/
```

Then install Angular Globally

```
sudo npm i -g angular/cli
```

Refer This Github issue [link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/503)

> Note Close Terminal and Open New Terminal and check

Comment: I did that, but I get the exact same error. Have no idea what to do.

Comment: alias ng="/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng" have you try this

Comment: then run `ng -v `

Comment: have you checked

Comment: Yes, it's still the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196307/discussion-between-orbit-and-mavinter).